# Encrypt excerpts in org file (passwords only)

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste, passwords

I keep project info in `.org` file together with passwords.

*When I share a screen it is annoying to show passwords in a buffer accidentally.*

I want to keep `.org` file in plain text format but mark some parts to be obfuscated or hidden or encrypted:

```
This is a normal text.
user: me
password: MAGIC{XXXX}
```

I want to be able to copy content marked as MAGIC as a plain text without a prompt for the decryption master password.

**UPDATE** I saw http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#HandlingEncryption
It encrypts entire section of org file and displays it in plain when prompted.

Displaying of passwords is dangerous. I want to hide them visually and without any manual instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution that hides passwords, but does not enctrypt:

```
(defvar mypasshide-prefix-re "^pass: *")

(defun mypasshide--toggle-display (overlay hide)
  "Hide or reveal region. Signature follows convention for
`reveal-toggle-invisible' from `reveal' mode."
  (if hide
      (overlay-put overlay 'display (propertize "****" 'face 'warning))
    (overlay-put overlay 'display nil)))

(defun mypasshide--hide ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward mypasshide-prefix-re nil t)
      (let* ((beg (match-end 0))
            (end (line-end-position))
            (overlay (make-overlay beg end)))
        (mypasshide--toggle-display overlay t)
        (overlay-put overlay 'reveal-toggle-invisible #'mypasshide--toggle-display)
        ))))

(define-minor-mode mypasshide-mode
  "Hide passwords after `mypasshide-prefix-re' and activate
`reveal-mode'. Disabling is not implemented."
  :group 'reveal
  (if mypasshide-mode
      (progn
        (mypasshide--hide)
        (reveal-mode))))

(provide 'mypasshide)
```

I activated it as `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'mypasshide-mode)`.